# How can I typeset *some* fields from a (YAML) dataset?

Tags: tables, datatool

I'm building a [dataset](http://www.maxheld.de/keynes) of sorts with long strings, tags, some of which will be used for survey research (a q-sort, actually).

This dataset needs to:

- be reasonably human-readable
- play nice with source control (git)
- accomodate long strings (sentences, or cues)
- allow nice typesetting (ideally by LaTeX)
- machine-readable for later input into a web-based questionnaire
- easily sortable
- play nice with R for later analysis

I also need to nicely print some of these fields (the long strings, actually) on little cards, and naturally, LaTeX would be my typesetter of choice for that purpose.

`.csv` – which can be readily imported to LaTeX – seems out of the question b/c of the long strings, and therefore, ugly git diffs.

So I recently (via Jekyll) came across `YAML`, which might just do the trick.

What would be a good way to import *select* fields from one or several `.yml`s to a LaTeX table?
I thought of:

1. Pandoc via its LaTeX templates
2. [This](https://github.com/jgm/yst) handy haskell tool
3. (ideally) some existing package on CTAN? (seems like listings won't help)

I *might* also be completely overthinking this whole issue and would appreciate any suggestions.

Maybe just make it a LaTeX table and worry about the rest later?

Here's what the (embryonic) dataset looks like:

```
---
ID: 1
Tags:
 - saving
 - normative
English:
 A good tax should encourage people to save for the future.
---
ID: 2
Tags:
 - tax
English:
 People should be taxed on what they spend.
...
```

Comment: Would be helpful if you provided examples of the data that we can work with?

Comment: I'd imagine you'd be using either LuaLaTeX or an external language to convert the YAML data to something else. Here's [a blog entry](http://mhyee.com/blog/yaml_resume.html) and [a Github repository](https://github.com/mhyee/resume) of someone doing something similar.